# How Do I import a local HTML file to my Swift Playground Live View?

Tags: swift3, swift-playground

The following is the code for importing local html file to swift playgrounds. It is not working but I'm getting a blank image in the Live View:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import PlaygroundSupport
let u = URL(string: "Prac_1.html")
let request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: u!) 
let webView=UIWebView(frame:CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:768.0,height:1024.0))
webView.loadRequest(request) //Loading the request
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = webView
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the HTML file to the Playground's "Resources" folder (go to "Navigator" > "Show project navigator" to display the folder).

Then use `Bundle.main.url(forResource:)` to fetch the file's URL, like this:

```
let u = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Prac_1", withExtension: "html")
```